# OPENCV :: Find all the points between two concentric circles

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, histogram

I have two concentric circles a and b, I detected the circles from the image, I know their Radii. What I want is the Points between the two concentric cirlces, So that I can extract the RGB values from those Points. Any help would be helpfull.

Comment: I know, I can find points on the circle using this x_perimeter = (int) x + (int) ((sin(i) * radius )) and similarly Y. But I want all the points between the circumference o two circles.

Comment: Hey Kishor! Can you show us why you have tried so far code wise? and thanks for using Stackoverflow hopefully you'll find an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indices (`x, y`) of the points between the two concentric circles (center (`x_0, y_0`), radii `r_0, r_1` with `r_1 > r_0`) have to fulfill the following condition:

```
(x-x_0) * (x-x_0) + (y-y_0) * (y-y_0) >= r_0 * r_0
(x-x_0) * (x-x_0) + (y-y_0) * (y-y_0) <= r_1 * r_1
```

So when looping over all point of an image you can figure out which points to process:

```
for (int x=0; x<img.rows; x++)
{
   for (int y=0; y<img.cols; y++)
   {
       double dd = (x-x_0) * (x-x_0) + (y-y_0) * (y-y_0);
       if (dd < r_0 * r_0 || dd > r_1 * r_1)
         continue;

       // Do what you have to do with the points between the two circles
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the ans. But I have a problem with processing time . Is there a faster way to do it. As I will be doing continuous streaming of frames from camera. Looping over the whole image would consume more time, I believe?

Comment: You should be only interested in area defined by center and radius of our largest circle. Thus you loop only through `for(int x = x_0 - r_1; x < x_0 + r_1; x++)` and similarly for `y`. In this case you should also check if you are not iterating over the boundries of an image

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
Make a Mat of the same size as your source image. 
Draw the two filled circles with the built-in OpenCV circle drawing routine. 
  (large circle in white, then the small in black) 
Use that as a mask, that you multiply on your source image. 
(Depending on which pixels you wish to keep, the mask may have to be inverted.)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to visit all pixels and somehow gather their colour values, and you only want to visit the pixels in question as speed is crucial, I would suggest that you look into the  [midpoint circle algorithm authored by Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm). You could specialize this so that you only get 2 or 4 points per pixel line, and traverse each line's pair(s) of points. Should be possible O(n), where n is height in pixels (diameter, ie largest radius), so you'd look at o(m), m being the number of pixels between the two pixels, instead of n^2. Would matter a lot if you have large images and radii close to each other.

[image]